# System.Data.SqlClient namespace on visual basic suddenly not been recognized anymore

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, namespaces

this what just happened today: System.Data.SqlClient  namespace on visual basic code suddenly not been recognized by the IDE, the code had no issues yesterday or any day before today, why would a namespace stop been recognized just like that. As usual all comments will be appreciated,greetings...

here is what visual basic is showing: below line #4 those curly lines appears which is not shown here...

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
```

Comment: Can you give an example of code that is not working?  Can you show the exact error you are getting?  Which specific class are you attempting to use?  Are your certain that you have added a reference to the proper assembly?

Comment: hey Chris, I haved added some lines in response for your question...imagine those lines visual studio usually shows when an error during design time must be fixed.If the visual does not recognized the line #4 will not recognized any sqlconnection,sqlcommand I need to use in my code which is the issue Im having now...greetings

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't have a problem if system.data doesnt have a squiggly too. When you type it in the imports for the class, does the intellisense pick it up and offer it for autocomplete?

id remove the system.data refefence in the solutions "properties -> references."  Then add it back.

Comment: thanks for the comment drewlander but it did not work,appreciate that,greetings

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved, had to uninstall visual and reinstall again and now Im not showing any issue like before,thanks for the help greetings